# cant ping IP address but can ping hostname

Tags: 16.04, networking

Curious why i cannot ping the IP address of a hostname , but can successfully ping the hostname.  As an example

```
host google.com
google.com has address 172.217.23.174

ping 172.217.23.174
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2015ms
```

Comment: Please show also the successful `ping google.com`, as promised.

Comment: your original post only shows a DNS lookup which is a different protocol & gets info from elsewhere, when compared to an ICMP echo request (or ping). it could be your network firewall(s) stop the echo-request; hence why AlexP requested you show your 'ping' for what you said worked.